# PrintDocument.Print in ASP.Net codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, printing

I'm trying to print directly to a network-available printer in a web application (VB.Net/ASP.Net). This is my code:

```
''' <summary>
''' Prints check on the printer.
''' </summary>
Public Sub PrintCheck()
    Dim p As New PrintDocument

    p.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = mPrinterPath
    p.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1
    p.PrinterSettings.Collate = True
    p.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1
    p.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 1
    p.OriginAtMargins = False
    p.DocumentName = "Check"
    AddHandler p.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPage
    p.Print()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Delegate for printing check.
''' </summary>
Private Sub PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs)
    'Vertical offset for printer internal margin.
    Dim voffset As Single = e.PageSettings.HardMarginX * 0.2545

    CreateGraphics(e.Graphics, voffset)
End Sub
```

CreateGraphics() is a sub which draws stuff on the page. I have tested the above code inside a windows application and it works. Also, this works fine when I run code inside IISExpress (VS 2013), but after publishing to IIS, it just doesn't work. No error page, no IIS logs. How can I make it work?

Comment: I have found a solution which was App. Pool Identity = Network Service. But I want a secure solution.

Comment: Are you sure that it even makes sense to print from the codebehind?  Normally you would print from the browser in a web app.  The `PrintDocument` class is specifically intended to be used in WinForms apps.

Comment: I your shoes, I'll abandon this idea immediately. Use some libraries like PdfSharp or similar to drawn into a pdf file and give this file to client via download.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj In fact this is part of a project for Dynamics AX 365 check printing. I cannot give a PDF to the user because: 1. It takes a lot of time to open PDF and print it (compared to direct printing method), and 2. Many PDF viewers add a 1-inch margin to top and left of page, causing all texts to move from their original positions and the check being voided. I have written code in a way that it cancels printer's internal margin to help all texts being placed in their right positions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney My reply to G3nt_M3caj explains why it makes sense. This is what Dynamics AX 365 is doing right now!

Comment: Hi @MohammadJavahery. You cannot replace a cloud based service with a simple web-based application. Even Azure, AWS, Red Hat or every Cloud based service doesn’t have control on client printers, to do that those need a plugin (RemoteApp or something else) in your browser which need as bridge from cloud/server and client. YOU CANNOT HAVE CONTROL ON CLIENT PRINTERS EVER by server side if you are using internet browsers. If you find a way to do that (Inshallah) I’m curious to know that. ;) .

Comment: could you share which permission is assigned to the printer? iis user does not have enough permission to access the printer so you need to set a user who has enough permission to access the printer or use network service which has enough permission to access the printer or set iis user permission to the printer.

Comment: Hi @G3nt_M3caj. Currently, D365 AX is doing what I'm trying to do! We give it printer's network address and it just prints from server directly without any plugin or something else. It doesn't print from client side as this printer is not defined on client neither it's driver is installed. We haven't had installed anything on client serving printer. Our D365 AX deployment is not cloud-based but is on-premises.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal We haven't had mangled printer's permissions. Everyone is allowed to print, Administrators allowed to manage printer. All are defaults. But with these printers, D365 AX is able to print. We cannot set IIS user permission on printer as the client serving printer is not the same as the server sending prints.

Comment: when click print does it ask for any confirmation pop up?

Comment: @MohammadJavahery now seems a little bit more clear. Howver put a Try-Catch and write errors on a file. txt to know what happens behind.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal In D365 AX or my code?! The former popups a dialog box to select printer from a list, or send output as a file. We already know that when we select printer, it sends data back to the server to be printed because we need to install drivers on all AOS servers and when printer path changes, we need to update some settings on all AOS servers too. But the latter only popups a window saying "printing page 1 of ..." which doesn't happen on IIS at all.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj as far as I know, if some exception happens, an error page should be displayed. This doesn't happen in my code.